# Bind multiple <form:select> to a List contained in a HashMap

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, hashmap, html-select

In my command obj myCmd there is a Map

```
private Map<Long, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Long, List<String>>();
```

And I hava a jsp that uses this command obj as its 'command'

```
<form:form commandName="myCmd">
```

Now I wanna bind a multiple select to a list in the map

```
<form:select multiple="true" path="map[${id}]">
```

but I got `javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: ServletException`

how should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
<form:select multiple="true" path="selectedValue">
    <form:options items="${map[${id}]}"></form:options>
</form:select>
```

where, `selectedValue` is a String variable in `myCmd` Class.